# How to convert string to given date format

Tags: c#

The below code is in MM/DD/YYYY format

```
string dateStr="9/7/1986";
```

But i want to change it like below format

```
dateStr="09/07/1986";
```

again same in MM/DD/YYYY format

Comment: The original date is not in MM/DD/YYYY format as you state. It's in M/d/yyyy format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work for you.

```
string dateStr = "9/7/1986";
string newDateStr= DateTime.Parse(dateStr).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

`newDateStr` will hold the value you need.

The best thing to do would be to use that format when you first convert the `DateTime` value to a `string`. Although, this would only work if you had it as a `DateTime` variable first.

Comment: @RiteshGupta Note that `DateTime.Parse` will except formats other than M/d/yyyy, depending on your situation that may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You could parse it to a `DateTime` then format it back to a `string`.

```
dateStr = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                  .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Note that you'll get exceptions if the `string` doesn't match the M/d/yyyy format.